# How to extract a list of external references from a excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm working on setting up an automated processing system for a (ever growing) unstructured collection of excel documents. The collection consists of both old-school `.xls` files and new `.xlsx` files. In my Java-based solution I am already making use of the Apache POI toolkit to analyse the documents.

One challenges that I have not been able to tackle yet, is how to identify links between documents so as to chart dependencies. I have not yet been able to figure out how to conveniently extract a list of external references. For `.xlsx` files I have a workaround in place that unzips the file, and opens the xml file holding the references. This works but is inefficient for large document collections, and also does not provide a solution for `.xls` files.

I prefer to have a solution that is not dependent on Microsoft Office or associated libraries as the solution needs to run on a Linux environment.

Is POI capable of doing this somehow? If not, what would be suggested libraries/tools/area's that I could further investigate?

Comment: The `Workbook` object has a `Connections` class.  You'll need the `CommandText` of the `OLEDBConnection`.  This will give you the linked workbook.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on the suggested solution? As far as I can tell from the documentation at https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/ , the `Workbook` interface (nor the implementing classes `HSSFWorkbook` and `XSSFWorkbook`) grant public access to underlying OLEDB connections.

Comment: You might have to branch out further than Apache-POI.  Have you looked into LibreOffice?  LibreOffice has an API and it can access the connections.

Comment: I think what you probably want for `.xls` / `HSSF` is the LinkTable, which holds references to other files used in formulas and names. Can you try looking in there?

Comment: I have updated to POI 3.11 beta (I was still using 3.10 final), which has a new `getExternalLinksTable()` function for `XSSFWorkbook`. So this solves the issue for .xlsx files.

Comment: I'm still not clear how to proceed on the `LinkTable` object in `HSSFWorkbook`. It is private and has no public accessor function.

@jbarker: I'm not ruling out possibilities yet, but the Libre Office API is quite cumbersome when compared to POI, which was why it was not selected as primary choice. I will dig further into it when I can't find an easy alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately I worked my way through the POI source code and used reflection to get a list of referenced external workbooks. The following code was tested to work on POI version 3.11 beta.

Note for people looking to use this method in there code: Because it deals with non-public methods and classes, it is subject to change and may break in the future.

```
private LinkedList<String> getWorkbookReferences(HSSFWorkbook wb) {
    LinkedList<String> references = new LinkedList<>();

    try {
        // 1. Get InternalWorkbook
        Field internalWorkbookField = HSSFWorkbook.class.getDeclaredField("workbook");
        internalWorkbookField.setAccessible(true);
        InternalWorkbook internalWorkbook = (InternalWorkbook) internalWorkbookField.get(wb);

        // 2. Get LinkTable (hidden class)
        Method getLinkTableMethod;
        getLinkTableMethod = InternalWorkbook.class.getDeclaredMethod("getOrCreateLinkTable", null);

        getLinkTableMethod.setAccessible(true);
        Object linkTable = getLinkTableMethod.invoke(internalWorkbook, null);

        // 3. Get external books method
        Method externalBooksMethod = linkTable.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getExternalBookAndSheetName", int.class);
        externalBooksMethod.setAccessible(true);

        // 4. Loop over all possible workbooks
        int i = 0;
        String[] names;
        try {
            while( true) {
                names = (String[]) externalBooksMethod.invoke(linkTable, i++) ;                     if (names != null ) {
                    references.add(names[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch  ( java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException e) {
            if ( !(e.getCause() instanceof java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException) ) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return references;
}
```

Comment: If you can find some commonality between the HSSF and XSSF Links Tables, open an enhancement request in the POI Bugzilla and ask for a common interface covering the two. That's the best way of getting a public class / method to support this!

Comment: Is there a way to update these links too