# DDE information in Excel

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I wrote a program to read excel files using Apache POI which is working as expected. Next part is to implement - "To reject reading excel file if it contains DDE links/information.

I read about DDE information via below links

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Data_Exchange
- http://jdde.pretty-tools.com/
- https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/win/z3ples.htm

  I could not get information on how
- an excel file looks like with DDE information.
- to identify an excel file that contains DDE information

  It would be great if someone can help me in understanding the above two points.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `XSSF` one could get the `List` of [ExternalLinksTables](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/ExternalLinksTable.html) from the `XSSFWorkbook` using [XSSFWorkbook.getExternalLinksTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#getExternalLinksTable--).

Then iterate through that `List`, get [CTExternalLink](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTExternalLink.java) for each `ExternalLinksTable` using [ExternalLinksTable.getCTExternalLink](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/ExternalLinksTable.html#getCTExternalLink--) and then check whether [CTExternalLink.isSetDdeLink](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTExternalLink.java#CTExternalLink.isSetDdeLink%28%29) is `true`. If so, we have a `DDE` link there.

External links like `='C:\Users\Paul\Documents\[2014 Budget.xlsx]Details'!$R$7` or `='http://teamsite.company.com/corporate/[MySpreadsheet.xlsx]‌​Sheet1'!F4` have nothing to do with `DDE`. There is no danger while using such links and so no reason to "reject reading excel file if it contains" such links. A `DDE` link looks like `=ddeapp|'parameters'!reference` in Excel. So we need to differ `DDE` links from others and only "reject reading excel file if it contains" **really** `DDE` links. Using [CTExternalLink.isSetDdeLink](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTExternalLink.java#CTExternalLink.isSetDdeLink%28%29) we are able to do this differentation.

I suspect the requirement "reject reading excel file if it contains DDE links" is about avoiding cell formulas like `=ddeapp|'parameters'!reference` in Excel. Using such formulas one could do really bad and dangerous things if the user is not attentively and is administrator. Example: `=cmd|'/C control'!anyname`. This will open system control application in Windows and if the user is administrator, then it would allow much more...

Since `DDE` is ancient technology from neolithic of IT, there are currently no good examples for using `DDE` in a productive way. You need a `ddeapp` which is a application which allows contact via `DDE` and returns a value then. This [youtube video: DDE Link Setup for DTN IQFeed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25ASh1N-q4w) shows  an example.

Comment: Below reference helped me to understand external reference. Able to verify for XLSX (XSSF workbook).  **Do we have any similar API to verify for XLS (HSSF Workbook)?**
[link] (http://ccm.net/forum/affich-603577-sharepoint-link-to-excel-via-a-cell-variable)
[link] (http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2024309&seqNum=8)
[link](https://www.maxwell.syr.edu/uploadedfiles/ict/training/handouts/handoutcreatingexternalreferencesinexcel2010.pdf)
[link] (http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/external-references.html)
[link] (https://www.excel-university.com/pull-external-data-into-excel/)

Comment: This link was useful in identifying external reference in a XLS file (HSSF workbook) [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758099/how-to-extract-a-list-of-external-references-from-a-excel-file)

Comment: Can you please share some simple examples in creating an excel file having DDE links?

Comment: Yes, the requirement is about "reject reading excel file if it contains DDE links". By using CTExternalLink.isSetDdeLink  I can identify whether XLSX file (XSSF workbook) has DDE links. Do we have similar API to identify DDE links in XLS file (HSSF workbook)?

Comment: @user650900: About `HSSF` I don't know much. But since `HSSF`, which is `BIFF8`, is similar ancient as `DDE`, it can be absolutely be that there all links are `DDE`. If so no differentition will be possible.

Comment: There is one niche where DDE is still in use: High-volume real-time data. DDE is rumored to be faster than COM, so it's quite common for measurement and trade exchange applications.